# BI Publisher .rtf Spacing if there is null value

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher

I am facing an issue on BI Publisher, I have some texts shown in a list.When they have value everything is fine , but when any of them is null then the space is held and shown empty line.Is it possible to wrap the empty line ?
You can notice my code above.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F47Kh.jpg "PDF"
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM0yn.jpg "RTF"

```
Observações:
COMMENTS
<?if@inlines: FORM = 'ABC' ?>This is a test . <?end if?>
<?if@inlines: STS = 'LATE' ?>TESTETSTS<?end if?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take off the @inlines. That's what is preventing the new lines.